# Use Angular $httpProvider in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to use AngularJS (which I'm new to) in combination with TypeScript while following the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).
[This](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/08/26/StrongTypingWithAngularJS.html) helped me a lot, but now I ran into the following problem:
I'm using the typing file from DefinitelyTyped which states that each `IServiceProvider` (which [`IHttpProvider`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L1296) inherits) has a [`$get`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L37) property.
While trying to use the `$httpProvider` service of Angular I need to call the [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) method (note: without the '$').

When trying to run this it fails because `$get` is undefined. I tried to change it to `get` temporarily in the browser and then the code works, so I'm confident that this is the problem.
I can't just use `get` in my TypeScript file, because it would fail to compile.

Now I'd like to know how to work around this problem?

*disclaimer: I'm not too comfortable with JavaScript in general either.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for [`IHttpService`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L1107) inorder to use http service. What you are looking at is the `Provider` recipe of `$http` ($httpProvider) which is used for global configuration during the `.config` phase of the application. Instead what you actually inject anywhere else is the instance of `$http` defined in the `$get` function of the `$httpProvider`.

Example usage of both interface definitions:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider:ng.IHttpProvider){...
```

and

```
class MyService implements IMyService {
   constructor(private $http:ng.IHttpService){
   }
 //...
}
```

Comment: Should be `app.config(['$httpProvider'], ($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) => { ...`